# using logic by looping

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am trying to make this mini guessing game. The user must guess the number. After 3 tries the user will be asked if he/she wants to continue or not. I have written the logic to make 3 questions with a prompt followed by the decision for the user to continue or kill the program. However i am trying to make it so that if the user continues he will keep playing.

I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10, what is it?> 3
10
your guess is too low
I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10, what is it?> 2
10
your guess is too low
I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10, what is it?> 5
6
your guess is too low
would you like to continue yes or no?(y for yes, n for no)> y
I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10, what is it?> 3
1
your guess is too high
would you like to continue yes or no?(y for yes, n for no)>

The yes or no question should not appear until the 3rd question mark. Anybody have any ideas or know what loop should be used to go in the right direction

These are the results above:

```
function game() {
    let numOfGuesses=0;
    let inputNum;
    
    while(numOfGuesses <= 10) {
    var userGuess = prompt("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10, what is it?");
    
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    
    let number = parseInt(userGuess);
    
    numOfGuesses++;
    console.log(randomNum)
    var quit;
    
    //logic to check which are correct and not correct
    if (userGuess < randomNum) {
        alert("your guess is too low")
    }else if(userGuess > randomNum) {
        alert("your guess is too high")
    }else {
        alert("CORRECT!")
    }
    
    if (numOfGuesses >= 3 || numOfGuesses == 3) {
        quit = prompt("would you like to continue yes or no?(y for yes, n for no)")
        //break;
        if(quit == "y") {
            continue;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    
    
    } 
}
game();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would separate it differently, creating an `askNumber(actualNumber)` function that would print the question and then print the response based on the user's guess, that way we can call this function indefinitely until the user gets it (that is if they want to keep playing)

Then you said you want to loop it three times, so we can try this

```
var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
function askNumber(actualNumber) {
    var correctGuess = false;
    var userGuess = parseInt(prompt("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10, what is it?"));

    //logic to check which are correct and not correct
    if (userGuess < actualNumber) {
        alert("your guess is too low");
    }else if(userGuess > actualNumber) {
        alert("your guess is too high");
    }else {
        alert("CORRECT!");
        correctGuess = true;
    }
    return correctGuess;

}
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    //If it is after the user's 3rd or 6th turn
    if (j == 3 || j == 6) {
        if (!confirm("Do you still want to keep playing?")) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (askNumber(randomNum) == true) {
        //Now you can refresh the website to play again
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: Im trying to if (j == 3 || j == 6) {
        if (!confirm("Do you still want to keep playing?")) {
            break;
        }
    } could you explain how this if statement works?

Comment: It asks the user if they want to keep playing with a confirm box, if the answer is "ok" then it returns true and the `for` loop does not break, but if they hit cancel then it returns false and the `for` loop breaks, effectively ending your game. You can then add a script to tell the user what the correct number actually was

Comment: So why does the randomNum variable not work inside the function?

Comment: I realized that as I was writing the code, it actually does, but just to keep it for the function's sake I decided to follow through with a parameter. But you are right! It works just as well without

Answer (score 0):

Define a counter and find its mode for each loop. It will give 0 for each 3 step

```js
function game() {
    let numOfGuesses=0;
    let inputNum;
    let counter = 1;
    while(numOfGuesses <= 10) {
        var userGuess = prompt("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10, what is it?");
        
        var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        
        let number = parseInt(userGuess);
        
        numOfGuesses++;
        console.log(randomNum)
        var quit;
        
        //logic to check which are correct and not correct
        if (userGuess < randomNum) {
            alert("your guess is too low")
        }else if(userGuess > randomNum) {
            alert("your guess is too high")
        }else {
            alert("CORRECT!")
        }
        
        if (counter % 3==0) {
            quit = prompt("would you like to continue yes or no?(y for yes, n for no)")
            //break;
            if(quit == "y") {
                continue;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
        counter++
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try this it came out with the same result